# Azure Application Insights not working properly for React Native

Tags: azure, react-native, azure-application-insights

I'm working on a React Native project and would like to integrate Azure Application Insights.

I have followed the official documentation provided here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript-react-native-plugin

While Application map displays request counts with relevant nodes further details on insights are not visible on clicking on the counts.

[image]

Also when it comes to Performance, Operations does not display any data while in Dependencies does.

[image]

Comment: There is a Server/Browser switch. Can you check whether you see telemetry when you switch to Browser?

Comment: @ZakiMa for Browser also Operations does not display any data

Comment: Does Dependencies tab show data for Browser switch?

Comment: @ZakiMa Yes for both Server/Browser it does show data

Comment: I think Operations doesn't show anything because for Browser telemetry it maps to PageViews. But for Single Page Apps it is not as useful (the whole app will be represented as one PageView which doesn't make sense). I think that react-native AI SDK doesn't collect them.

Comment: And I think that Application Map doesn't show any transitions here because again for main node there is no data.

Comment: If you do have a concept of operations then you can call appInsights.trackPageView() manually (and if you do it at startup then both Application Map and Performance will start showing such page views).

Comment: @ZakiMa I again added configurations using the library available for React which did provide Application Map. But prefer not using this it since it does not provide device data on user information. As you said not getting Browser telemetry might be because of Single Page App. Thanks for your response and explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [ZakiMa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3646920/zakima). I am posting your discussion as answer as it will benefit other community users.

> Operations are not visible because for Browser telemetry maps to
> PageViews. But for Single Page Apps, whole app will be represented as
> one PageView. Application Map doesn't show any transitions as there is
> no data for main node.